# What is the name of the extensions that allow you to add apps the share-button

Tags: android, ios

The stuff that allows you to add apps here:

[image]

and here:
[image]

I'm looking for the thing that describes the document-type, for example tell the sharing that it's a document or a photo.

Comment: Um, do you mean the MIME type that you put on the `Intent` for `ACTION_SEND`?

Comment: Do you mean like Bottom Sheet? https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html#

Comment: It is ShareApp Extension in iOS.

Comment: In your app, register Intent Filter in manifest for e.g. pictures mime type: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving

Comment: @PiyushRathi I found this, https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/ what I would like to tell iOs what kind of file it is so that I can allow other apps to use their actions on the file.

Comment: @Himmators what kind of file mean?